# OpenGL 3.3: render to framebuffer w/o depth attachment

Tags: opengl, frame-buffer

I want to render my scene to a framebuffer and store the RGBA values in a texture. For this, I attach a texture to GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0. When I define a GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT texture as well, everything is rendered with the correct depth. However, if I leave out the depth attachment (because I don't need it in a later stage), wrong depth values are output, if I further use the RGBA texture (e.g. when blitting the framebuffer to another one).

Is this correct behavior, i.e. do I always need to specify a depth attachment?

**edit:** *wrong depth values:* By attaching a GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, a color texture (e.g. RGBA) is output. Without a depth attachment, the colors are at the wrong "depth", in the sense that the pixels of an object behind a wall are rendered, although the corresponding pixels of the wall should be rendered instead.

Regards,
bobbel

Comment: If you don't have a depth attachment, how are incorrect depth values output?  There's nowhere for those depth values to be output to..

Comment: This is indeed a good argument :D I edited the question appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to attach *something* to `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT` if you want to render with depth testing and writing, but it doesn't have to be a texture. If you don't need to read the contents of the depth buffer in a shader (e.g. for shadow mapping), you can use a [Renderbuffer](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Renderbuffer_Object) object instead. Using a Renderbuffer object for the depth buffer may offer a performance benefit over using a texture.